# How to extract Log-Data from Azure Log Analytics / Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am struggling to understand where Azure does store logs and how I can access and export them.

Is there some kind of interface I can use? I've been at it in the official Documentation for hours but cannot seem to find anything definite on how to get the data OUT of azure.

I anyone can help me understand the topic better or has any advice or resources to share, any input is appreciated. :)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options, you can for example [enable continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) for Application Insights:

> Continuous Export is ideal for this. The events you see in the Application Insights portal can be exported to storage in Microsoft Azure in JSON format. From there, you can download your data and write whatever code you need to process it.

Another option is using the [App Insights Rest Api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/):

> Query and integrate with the performance, availability and usage data collected by Application Insights for your application

Comment: Thanks, that is just the kind of answer I was hoping for. I'll look into the continuous export right away. Do you, by chance, have any good resources on hand?

Comment: @Maetness The continuous export has worked great, but to easily export existing data, I found this handy tool + walkthrough on a Microsoft blog: [Export Historical Data from Log Analytics (microsoft.com)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/export-historical-log-data-from-microsoft-sentinel/ba-p/3413418)